# get data from ajax/ javascript call and populate chosen plugin multiple select

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery-chosen

I searched the all over for this matter and could not find any resource to help me put. If am reposting this question I aplogie in advance.

What I need to do is to `echo` out the data of a json object which is fetched from ajax/ javascript call through a rest controller.Both the php and the ajax calls are in the same page and I just cant find a work around to get though this matter. following is the area i want to echo out the data,

```
<div>
    <em>Tags</em>
    <select data-placeholder="Tag your question here" style="width:350px;" multiple class="chosen-select" tabindex="8">
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php 
            foreach($jsonObj as $obj){
                echo "<option>".$obj->tagName."</option></br>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

and following is the javascript/ ajax call which is in the same page,

```
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
    function doGetTag() {
        alert('here');     

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php/rest/resource/qtag',
            //data: data,               
            success: function(data) {
                var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);                    
            },
            type: "get"     
        });
 }   
</script>
```

My requirement is to assign `$jsonObj` in php code segment with the contents of `var tagObj` which is in the javascript segment of the same page OR a way to turn the ajax JSON reponse to html code `<option> json value </option>` format. Your expert advice is greatly appreciated on this matter.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Are you sure that the ajax call returning json formatted text?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, javascript runs on the client, you can't insert javascript into PHP

Comment: @silentboy yes :) i have tested and it is handled by the rest controller. it returns a json

Comment: @adeneo I am aware :) but this is a view which has both php and javascript/ ajax. the ajax calls retrieve data from the rest controller which is on the server side which is again php :)

Comment: @Hasitha Where is the doGetTag() Call?

Comment: Well, you have two option. You fetch the json and make the form on the fly in the client side. Or, Make the form on server side and attach it to the html page with ajax.

Comment: I get that it's a view, and that the ajax call is getting data from PHP, but you still have to use javascript to insert the content, something like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dJK79/1/)

Comment: @silentboy hmm thanks for the tip i will check on that

Comment: @adeneo ohhh okey i will double check on that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript itself to update the content since you're getting response through AJAX.

Eg.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doGetTag() {

    $.ajax({
            url: 'json_data.php',
            //data: data,               
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
                $('.chosen-select').html('<option value=""></option>');

                $.each(jsonObj, function (key, value) {
                    var opt = '<option>'+value+'</option>';
                    $('.chosen-select').append(opt);
                });             
            },
            type: "get"     
        });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<?php

$jsonObj=array('0' => "Mercedes", '1' => "Ferrari", '2' => "Volkswagen");

?>

    <em>Tags</em>
    <select data-placeholder="Tag your question here" style="width:350px;" multiple class="chosen-select" tabindex="8">
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php 
            foreach($jsonObj as $key=>$value){

                echo "<option>".$value."</option></br>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <p><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="doGetTag();">doGetTag</a></p>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

json_data.php (Example!)

```
<?php
echo '{"3":"Mercedes-New","4":"Ferrari-New","c":"Volkswagen-New"}';
?>
```

Comment: thank you for the reply :) but why have hard coded the json obkject within the php tag? i need it to be dynamically fetched :) can you do a bit of explaining. :) i am new to this

Comment: @Hasitha Hard Coded json string in json_data.php was Just to demonstrate Your JSON response from index.php/rest/resource/qtag because I didn't have any other data to give an example for you..:)